# Solidity multiple variables assignment ends up with null

Tags: solidity

Contract code:

```
contract RecordStore{
  struct Record {
    string value;
    address owner;
  }

  mapping(string => Record) records;
  Record lastRecord;

  function addRecord(string _recordId, string _value, address _owner) returns (bool) {
    Record r = records[_recordId];
    r.value = _value;
    r.owner = _owner;
    lastRecord = r;
    return true;
  }

  function getLastRecordOwner() returns (addr) {
    return lastRecord.owner;
  }

}
```

Client code:

```
  var rs = RecordStore.deployed();
  var account = web3.eth.getAccounts()[0];
  var recordName = "test_name";

  rs.addRecord(recordName, account, recordName, account, {from:account}).then(function(res) {

    rs.getLastRecordOwner.call().then(function(lastRecord) {
      console.log("last record owner: " + lastRecord);
    });

  });
```

When I run the test on testrpc everything works as expected.  But when I run it on geth `lastRecord` is null.  Does anyone know why?

Comment: When you say it works on geth, do you mean on the live network or with the `--dev` flag? Also, it's likely an issue with your deployment/interaction, not with the contract, so you should post your process for testing

Comment: @TjadenHess I'm not running with --dev.  I'm running geth locally with a local chain (using my own genesis json).  I've been using truffle and do `truffle migrate --reset` for deploy.

Answer (score 2):

it works for me this is the code with minor changes

```
contract test{
  struct Record {
    string value;
    address owner;
  }

  mapping(string => Record) records;
  Record lastRecord;

  function addRecord(string _recordId, string _value, address _owner) returns (bool) {
    Record r = records[_recordId];
    r.value = _value;
    r.owner = _owner;
    lastRecord = r;
    return true;
  }

  function getLastRecordOwner() returns (address) {
    return lastRecord.owner;
  }

}
```

[image]

Comment: Do you know if this is ran on testrpc?

Comment: The browser compiler uses testrpc, yes

Comment: Ok.  Yeah - the contract works fine in testrpc.  But it doesn't work in geth.